Calculating trace of inverse of a random matrix
I am trying to calculate $\frac{1}{r}$Tr$((\mathbf{I}_r-B)^{-1})$ where $\mathbf{I}_r$ is the identity matrix and B is a random  $r$ by $r$ matrix given by $B = O^{T} DO$, where  $O_{n\times r}$ is the first $r$ columns of a Haar distributed random matrix and $D= \text{diag}(d_1, \cdots, d_n)$ with each $d_i\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{d_i} \to \mu$ weakly (or let say all the moments converge too) to some Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ (supported away from one).
I want to be able to calculate (come up with an expression for the limit of the quantity $\frac{1}{r}$Tr$((\mathbf{I}_r-B)^{-1})$ with $r$ fixed and letting $n\to \infty$ (with some stronger assumptions than weak convergence if required). I can calculate the limit explicitly when $r=1$ and $r=n$, which I explain now.
For $r=1$, we have $\frac{1}{r}$Tr$((\mathbf{I}_r-B)^{-1})= \frac{1}{1- \sum_{i=1}^{n} d_i o_i^2}$ where $o=(o_1, \cdots, o_n)$ is a uniformly distributed  point on the unit sphere $\mathbf{S}^{n-1}$. We can sample $o= \frac{g}{\|g\|_2}$ for a standard Gaussian vector $g \sim N(0, I_n)$ and by concentration of norms of Gaussian vectors $\sum_{i=1}^{n} d_i o_i^2 \to \mathbb{E}_{\mu}[X]$ almost surely. So $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ Tr$((\mathbf{I}_1-B)^{-1}) =\frac{1}{1- \mathbb{E}_{\mu}[X]}$.
For $r=n$ we have  $O^TO= \mathbf{I}_n= OO^T$ and $\frac{1}{r}Tr((\mathbf{I}_n -B)^{-1})= \frac{1}{n}Tr((O^T( \mathbf{I}_n -D)O)^{-1})= \frac{1}{n}Tr(O^T( \mathbf{I}_n -D)^{-1}O)= \frac{1}{n}Tr((\mathbf{I}_n -D)^{-1})= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1-d_i} \to S_{\mu}(1)$ where $S_{\mu}: \mathbf{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the Stieltjes transform of $\mu$ given by $S_{\mu}(z)= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{d\mu(\lambda)}{z-\lambda}$.

super interesting question! maybe we can first consider the r=n square O case and then add projection matrix on both side to get down from n to r? just a thought

For real symmetric matrices $M$, first consider the trace of resolvent
$$g_M(z)=\frac 1rTr[(zI_r-M)^{-1}]$$
In your case, we just want to compute $g_B(1)$.
Note this quantity is related to a few other things
$$t_M(z)=\frac 1rTr[M(zI_r-M)^{-1}]$$
They are related by
$$g_{M}(z)=\frac{1+t_{M}(z)}{z}$$
So it suffices to compute any of these for your matrix $B$.
First construct the full square $\bar O$ matrix, $\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$. Then let $C=\bar O^T D\bar O$.
$$g_C(z) =g_{\bar O^T D\bar O}(z)\\
=\frac 1rTr[(zI_r-\bar O^T D\bar O)^{-1}]\\
=\frac 1rTr[(zI_r-D)^{-1}]\\
=g_D(z)
$$
The orthogonal transform won't affect the spectrum so it won't affect $g(z)$ and $t(z)$ functions.
Then let $O$ be the first $r$ column of $\bar O$. We can define square projection matrix $P$, with first $r$ diagonal values 1, the rest 0. We can write as $O=\bar O \Pi$, with $\Pi$ $n\times r$ matrix, the first r columns of $P$
Then
$$B=\Pi^T\bar O D\bar O\Pi=\Pi^TC\Pi$$
Basically, $B$ is selecting the first $r$ column and rows of the matrix $C$.
Note $P^TCP$ has the same first $r\times r$ square as $\Pi^TC\Pi$, but has all the other entries 0.
Since $\Pi^TC\Pi$ and $P^TCP$ have the same non-zero eigen spectra, their $t$ transforms can be related
$$rt_{\Pi^TC\Pi}(z)=n t_{P^TCP}(z)\\
\rightarrow t_{B}(z)=\frac n r t_{P^TCP}(z)
$$
So the inverse function of $t$ transform $\zeta_M=t_M^{-1}$ are also related
$$
\rightarrow \zeta_B(t)=\zeta_{P^TCP}(\frac r n t)
$$
Let $q=r/n$
Thus the S transform of these can be related
$$S_{B}(t)=\frac {1+t}{\zeta_B(t)t}\\
=\frac {1+t}{\zeta_{P^TCP}(qt)t}
$$
$$S_{P^TCP}(qt)=\frac {1+qt}{\zeta_{P^TCP}(qt)qt}$$
Thus
$$
S_{B}(t)=\frac {1+t}{t}\frac{qt}{1+qt}S_{P^TCP}(qt)\\
S_{B}(t)=\frac {q(1+t)}{1+qt}S_{P^TCP}(qt)
$$
As $P^TCP=PCP$, in free probability theory, it's a free product $PCP=P*C=P*D$
Then the $S transform suffices the multiplicative property.
$S_{P^TCP}(qt)=S_{P}(qt)S_C(qt)$
For square projection matrix $P$ (keeping r out of n dimension) we know
$$S_{P}(t)=\frac{t+1}{t+q}$$
$$S_{P}(qt)=\frac{qt+1}{qt+q}$$
Thus
$$S_{B}(t)=\frac {q(1+t)}{1+qt}S_{P^TCP}(qt)\\
=\frac {q(1+t)}{1+qt}S_{P}(qt)S_C(qt)$\\
=\frac {q(1+t)}{1+qt}\frac{qt+1}{qt+q}S_C(qt)\\
=S_C(qt)\\
=S_D(qt)
$$
Note
$$t_D(z)=zg_D(z)-1\\
=-1+z\int \frac{d\mu(\lambda)}{z-\lambda}$$
Assume we can calculate $t_D(z)$, let $\zeta_D(t)$ be its inverse
$$S_D(t)=\frac{t+1}{t\zeta_D(t)}$$
and also definition of $S$ transform
$$t_B(z)=\frac 1{z S_B(t)-1}$$
The desired quantity
$$g_B(1)=t_B(1)+1$$
The $t_B(1)=\tau$ suffices the self consistency equation
$$t_B(1)=\tau=\frac 1{S_B(\tau)-1}=\frac 1{S_D(q \tau)-1}$$
$$\tau=\frac 1{S_D(q \tau)-1}$$
$$\tau=\frac {1}{\frac{q \tau+1}{q \tau \zeta_D(q \tau)} -1}$$
with the desired quantity
$$g_B(1)=\frac 1rTr[(I_r-M)^{-1}]=\tau+1$$
